# I havn't enable Javascript in Internet explorer 8

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, intranet

I have tried to enable Javascript in my computer, and I just downloaded Internet 
Explorer 8.

I tried to look up how to enable it a couple of times, but it inly shows 
how to enable Internet 7 and down..

I can't really do everything I do on myspace, and it's stressing me out. 
please help!!!

Comment: IE7 and IE8 have their enable-JavaScript switches in exactly the same place.

Answer (score -1):

OR Download any of the pretty standard browser

http://www.google.com/chrome

http://www.mozilla.com/en-US/firefox/firefox.html

http://www.opera.com/

http://www.apple.com/safari/download/

http://flock.com/